# Can I disable parameter pattern matching?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection

Angular has a feature in which in some cases it will attempt to automagically match parameters with values. IE:

```
angular.module("foo").controller(function($scope){
  //Angular will automatically fill in the value of $scope
}
```

This of course runs into issues when dealing with minification, which is why we use the array syntax.

Is it possible to disable this feature of Angular though? I ask because I recently had a bug where some of my code was working in unminified form, but failing in minified and the root cause ended up being a variable that was unexpectedly being auto-filled by Angular.

Since I know that all my code is (or at least should) be written using the array syntax I would like to disable this feature so that I can force out any other hidden bugs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes and it's called *explicit injection* with *strict dependency injection* enabled:

```
angular.module("foo").controller("SomeController", ["$scope", function($scope){
  //Angular will automatically fill in the value of $scope
}]);
```

...or:

```
 function SomeController($scope){
      //Angular will automatically fill in the value of $scope
  }

  SomeController.$inject = ["$scope"];
  angular.module("foo").controller("SomeController", SomeController);
```

> Since I know that all my code is (or at least should) be written using
>   the array syntax I would like to disable this feature so that I can
>   force out any other hidden bugs.

You can disable automatic parameter matching using *strict dependency injection*. See Angular's [production guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/production) to get further details:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-strict-di>
  <!-- your app here -->
</div>
```

...or:

```
angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp'], {
  strictDi: true
});
```

Comment: Not really what he was asking for as he was asking how to disable parameter matching.

Comment: @mccainz and this is what explicit injection does. It disables automatic parameter matching

Comment: As @mccainz mentioned, I already know of this syntax and I mentioned it in my question. What I'm looking for is a global Angular option to disable the 'simple' style that doesn't use arrays

Comment: @DavidGrinberg See my update. You can disable automatic parameter matching with strict di enabled..

Comment: Now that's an answer, +1 as I was unaware of that feature.

Comment: @mccainz or it has been completed ;P